# What will be ajax response format for group data in tabulator?

Tags: javascript, ajax, tabulator

I want to know the ajax response format for data in the following table?

[image]

In my case groupValues will be dynamic also.

```
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    height:"311px",
    movableRows:true,
    groupBy:"col",
    groupValues:[["green", "blue", "purple"]]
    columns:[
        {rowHandle:true, formatter:"handle", headerSort:false, frozen:true, width:30, minWidth:30},
        {title:"Name", field:"name", width:150},
        {title:"Progress", field:"progress", formatter:"progress", sorter:"number"},
        {title:"Gender", field:"gender"},
        {title:"Rating", field:"rating", formatter:"star", formatterParams:{stars:6}, hozAlign:"center", width:120},
        {title:"Favourite Color", field:"col"},
        {title:"Date Of Birth", field:"dob", hozAlign:"center", sorter:"date"},
        {title:"Driver", field:"car", hozAlign:"center", formatter:"tickCross"},
    ],
});
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are only two type of ajax response needed for the table, for paginated and unpaginated data. all other layout options are generated by the table itself and not represented in the data array.

As you don't appear to be using pagination the standard format would be a JSON encoded array:

```js
[
    {"id":1, "name":"bob", "age":"23"},
    {"id":2, "name":"jim", "age":"45"},
    {"id":3, "name":"steve", "age":"32"}
]
```

Details of this can be found in the [Ajax Documentation](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.9/data#ajax-response)

You just need to make sure you set the `groupBy` property in your table definition and specify the property in each row object that should be used to group it:

```js
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    groupBy:"age",
});
```

If you want to change the field that things are grouped by once the table has been built, you can use the `setGroupBy` function on the table.

```js
table.setGroupBy("gender");
```

Details of this can be found in the [Grouping Data Documentation](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.9/group)

#### Group by Values

When you choose to use the `groupValues` option, all this does is tell Tabulator that those are the groups that will be created, in your case "green", "blue" and "purple".

The `groupBy` option then tells Tabulator which field in the row data to look at to determine which group the data should be in, when the value of that field matches one of the values in your `groupValues` array it is then added to that group.

If you dont want that column to be visible in the data that is fine, simply set the `visible` property of the column to `false` and it will be hidden from view but still used to group the data

```js
 {title:"Favourite Color", field:"col", visible:false},
```

Comment: I don't want to group by column. I want to group by groupValues

Comment: You have to choose a column that contains those values, then Tabulator will arrange the rows into those groups based on the values in those columns

Comment: Rajan, please don't mark down the answer i have provided. I literally wrote the Tabulator library so the answer i have provided is factually correct. Just because you many not like it does not mean it is wrong. I have updated the answer to explicitly explain how the group by values system works